# Is it possible to send to n clients data at the same time using Tcp Sockets?

Tags: android, sockets, clients

I am trying to set up a Socket server. I have managed to communicate with a client. What i am trying to do is to send the same responses more clients, lets say 2. Is this possible? Can anyone provide a hint?

Answer (score 1):

The technology you're describing is multicast, but you probably should not be using it. Instead, create seperate threads on the server for each client, so that they communicate with each other at the same time.

Comment: And how communication is achieved? Can u provide a hint or something?